# How do I find data types in Rails documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, return-value, duck-typing, rails-activerecord

Relatively new to Ruby, and I am having a lot of trouble with documentation. My main problem is, how do I tell what type of object is returned from a method?

If I take a look at Objective-C or Java docs, I can see:

> FunctionX returns object of type Y.

I can click on Y and find out all about that class. Contrast that with ActiveRecord::Base's [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html). If I look at the `#connection` method, it tells me:

```
Returns the connection currently associated with the class.
```

What the heck is a connection? I want to find out more about the connection object's class. Doesn't every method specify what the return type is?

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: How do I tell in docs what the return type is....

Comment: Also note that the docs include a "Show Source" link for each method that will *show* you what's returned by that method, but that may not leave you any wiser if you insist on expecting static types.

Comment: @CodeGnome ah I see. So I have to read the source to understand what's returned...kind of defeats one of the purposes of classes/encapsulation doesn't it?

Comment: @0xSina Not really. Ruby objects are more mutable, so the class hierarchy tells you less than you think once you account for mixins and singletons. If you *want* static typing or immutable return values, Ruby is probably not the right choice for your problem.

Comment: @CodeGnome It's not about wanting static or dynamic typing... I am just merely trying to understand how people who work with ruby on a day to day basis understand documentation.

Answer (score 2):

#### Ruby Uses Duck-Typing

Ruby doesn't use types the way you think. A method just returns whatever expression was evaluated last. You can do whatever you want with the return values, including:

1. `#inspect` it.
2. Ask its `#class`.
3. See if it will `#respond_to?` some method.
4. Whatever else you might want to do with it.

#### As to Your Question...

The Rails documents are fairly thorough for the things you're generally expected to touch in an application, but they can be a little less clear about the internals. Still, the API documentation for [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) doesn't seem unclear at all.

> Connections are usually created through ::establish_connection and retrieved by #connection. All classes inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base will use this connection.

For practical purposes, you'll get back an object that describes a database connection which is usually defined in your `config/database.yml` file. For example:

```
$ rails runner 'puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class'
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter
```

If you're trying to understand Rails internals, you may have to chase some deeply-nested method calls and understand the Ruby metaprogramming (e.g. [BasicObject#method_missing](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing)) that underpins the framework. However, you could just save yourself a lot of trouble by using duck-typing to deal with the returned objects.